# Keep time zone information when converting POSIX object to string

Tags: r, datetime, posix

I'm trying to convert a POSIX object to a string in R by using

`as.character(Sys.time())` which returns `"2021-09-28 08:38:13"`

However, if I just run `Sys.time()` I get `"2021-09-28 08:38:13 CEST"`.

How do I get the time zone information to be converted to the string, too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use option `usetz = TRUE`

```
as.character(Sys.time(), usetz = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `format` with `'%Z'` to denote timezone.

```
format(Sys.time(), '%Y-%m-%d %T %Z')
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `strftime(`.

```
strftime(Sys.time(), '%c')
# [1] "Tue 28 Sep 2021 08:43:06 CEST"
```

or

```
strftime(Sys.time(), '%F %X %Z')
# [1] "2021-09-28 08:45:42 CEST"
```

Answer (score 3):

The same thing could be done with `format` with `usetz = TRUE`:

```
format(Sys.time(), usetz = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
2021-09-28 08:38:13 CEST
```

## Timings:

```
a <- proc.time()
for (i in 1:100000)
{
format(Sys.time(), usetz = TRUE)
}
print(proc.time() - a)
b <- proc.time()
for (i in 1:100000)
{
as.character(Sys.time(), usetz = TRUE)
}
print(proc.time() - b)
```

`format` (mine) is quicker than `as.character` (Park's answer). The output is:

```
   user  system elapsed 
 11.040   0.520  11.563 
   user  system elapsed 
 11.930   0.290  12.229
```

The second one is Park's.

Comment: Try `x <- rep(Sys.time(), 1e4); microbenchmark::microbenchmark(as.character=as.character(x, usetz = TRUE), format=format(x, '%Y-%m-%d %T %Z'), strftime=strftime(x, '%F %X %Z'),format2=format(x, usetz = TRUE))`.